# File upload with post parameter in curl

Tags: facebook, post, curl

How to make a request for uploading a file to facebook using graph api in curl

I am making this request but getting Error:

```
curl https://graph.facebook.com/<id>/photos  -F "source=@me.jpg"  -d "message=Me"  -v 

ERR:

Only One Http Request can be Selected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mix -F and -d options in the same command line. If you want a multipart formpost (which I believe you do) then you need to add all parts with -F, including the "message=Me" part.